# Single Hibernate Connection with Multiple Session

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Is it possible to have single connection open with a database and have multiple sessions inside that connection with Hibernate.

e.g.,

```
// create session from Thread 1.
try {    
tx = session.beginTransaction();
// do something which is taking time.
tx.commit();
}  
catch (Exception exp) {
 tx.rollback();

 }
 //Now thread 2 comes and begin session 
 try {    
 tx = session.beginTransaction();
// do something
tx.commit();
} 
catch (Exception exp) {
tx.rollback();

}
```

Query is will Hibernate allow this thing as first session is not closed and 1st thread is using it.

Answer (score 0):

A connection is provided by the pool to the application (a Hibernate session, in this case). The application uses this connection and returns it to the pool. The pool will decide whether to discard this connection or to reuse it in the future for another session. So, two different sessions can end up using the same connection, but not at the same time